# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: bash, quoting

I have a BASH project and I face two errors that I do not understand.

Here is my BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash

proc_name=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f1 | uniq`;
proc_freq=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_core=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_hyperthreading=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'siblings' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_architecture=`lscpu | grep '64-bit' | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d'-' -f1`;
proc_cache_L1=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L1i' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L2=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L2' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L3=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L3' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_virtualisation=`lscpu | grep 'Virtualisation' | cut -d':' -f2 |sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2` | tr ',' '.'`

ip_infos_addr_ipv4=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet adr:/{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`;
ip_infos_addr_ipv6=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/adr inet6:/{print $3}'`;
ip_publique_addr=`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`;
carte_reseau=`lspci |grep Ethernet | cut -d":" -f3`;


echo -e "$proc_name\n$proc_freq\n$proc_core\n$proc_hyperthreading\n$proc_architecture\n$proc_cache_L1\n$proc_cache_L2\n$proc_cache_L3\n$proc_virtualisation\n$proc_load_average\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv4\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv6\n$ip_publique_addr\n$carte_reseau" > Collecteur/collecteur_cpu_reseau.txt;
```

And here are the two mistakes I have:

```
./collecteur_cpu_reseau: line 17: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./collecteur_cpu_reseau: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: shellcheck.net is useful in these situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the **unnecessary quote** in `line 12` :

```
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2` | tr ',' '.'`
# _______________________________________________________________^   

                                                         ^
```

Therefore the script without error would be :

```
#!/bin/bash

proc_name=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f1 | uniq`;
proc_freq=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_core=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_hyperthreading=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'siblings' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_architecture=`lscpu | grep '64-bit' | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d'-' -f1`;
proc_cache_L1=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L1i' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L2=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L2' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L3=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L3' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_virtualisation=`lscpu | grep 'Virtualisation' | cut -d':' -f2 |sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
# corrected line
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2 | tr ',' '.'`

ip_infos_addr_ipv4=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet adr:/{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`;
ip_infos_addr_ipv6=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/adr inet6:/{print $3}'`;
ip_publique_addr=`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`;
carte_reseau=`lspci |grep Ethernet | cut -d":" -f3`;


echo -e "$proc_name\n$proc_freq\n$proc_core\n$proc_hyperthreading\n$proc_architecture\n$proc_cache_L1\n$proc_cache_L2\n$proc_cache_L3\n$proc_virtualisation\n$proc_load_average\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv4\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv6\n$ip_publique_addr\n$carte_reseau" > Collecteur/collecteur_cpu_reseau.txt;
```